# how to run rake for a specific app?

Tags: git, heroku

I have created a heroku rails app, In my local rails app folder, I've added another remote repo for testing that points to another rails app at heroku too.

But, how can I run heroku rake for the other testing app while I am on the same app directory?

**EDIT**

the folder name is `dcaclab`

the app name is `dcaclab`

but, I want to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` for another project rather dcacalb

Comment: same app directory but different file name. right?

Comment: same app directory, but different app name at heroku, I think I have to add the app name beside the command?

Comment: can you mention here your app name or folder name which inside the rails app folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify an application with the --app flag following the rake task

$> heroku run rake db:migrate --app my_other_app_name

Answer (score 0):

It may work for you, if your directory like this

```
--Main_app_folder
  --dcaclab
  --dcac
```

I hope your project name same as you project folder.

If you want to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` on `dcaclab`, then on your command prompt directory as `Main_app_folder/dcaclab>`. esle if you want to run rake task on `dcac`, then on your command prompt directory should be `Main_app_folder/dcac>`

Hope It will helpful to you.